# Include a PHP page based on URL retrieved from an SQL database using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page, `index.php`, with `<select>` `<options>` which act as filters. Through Ajax, information is retrieved from an SQL database and echoed into a `<div>` on the same page. One of the fields that is echoed contains the URL to another page such as `a1701.php`.  Thus far, everything works perfectly.

However, rather than having the URL displayed, I would like the content of  the page e.g. `a1701.php` to be displayed in the same way it would be if I had used `<?php include 'a1701.php' ?>`.

I have read a lot of posts on SO but haven't found any describing this situation (maybe I am looking for the wrong thing in which case please advise). Following the advice of other partially-related posts, I have tried several things including:

- using absolute rather than relative links with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
- `include 'a1701.php';` vs `echo "<?php include 'a1701.php'; ?>"`
- using `&lt;` instead of `<` etc.
- reloading specific `<div>`s (I haven't actually tried this because I can't figure out what code I would have to put where to make it work.)

I have tried more than one URL and have checked that each one is correct.

```
index.php
```

```html
<script>
    function filterQuestions() {
     var selectCount = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length;
     var str = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < selectCount; i++) {
      if (document.getElementsByTagName("select")[i].value != "") {
      str[i] = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[i].name+"="+document.getElementsByTagName("select")[i].value;       
      }
     }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();       
    } else {
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("questionList").innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","filter.php?"+str.join("&"),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    
    

  <select name="branch" onchange="filterQuestions()">
   <option value="All">All branches</option>
   <option value="Number">Number</option>
   <option value="Trigonometry">Trigonometry</option>
  </select>
  <select name="topic" onchange="filterQuestions()">
   <option value="All">All topics</option>
   <option value="sinrule">Sine Rule</option>
   <option value="cosrule">Cosine Rule</option>
  </select>
```

```
filter.php
```

```html
<?php
$branch = $_GET["branch"];
$topic = $_GET["topic"];

if($branch != "All") {
 $wherefilter[] = "branch = '".$branch."'";
}
if($topic != "All") {
 $wherefilter[] = "topic = '".$topic."'";
}
$where = join(" AND ", $wherefilter);

if($where != NULL) {
 $where = " WHERE $where";
}

mysqli_select_db($link,"generator");
$sql="SELECT question_name, url FROM questions".$where;
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['question_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['url'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $pagelink = $row['url'] . '.php'; /* URL is correct */
    echo"<br>";
    echo $pagelink;
    echo"<br>";
    echo "<?php include '" . $pagelink . "'; ?>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<?php include '" . $pagelink . "'.php; ?>"; /* doesn't work */
    include $pagelink; /* doesn't work */
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

```
a1701.php
```

contains the content I want included. I have tried including other content too.

Is there a way to achieve what I am after? Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a1701.php to execute and output some html which would be inserted into the div. Is that right?

Comment: @ryantrx, that's correct.

Comment: @ryantrx, I may have misunderstood what you were asking, so to clarify:  
  `a1701.php` is not where the Ajax request is sent.    `a1701.php` is just content that I want to be included in `index.php` (a field in the database returns a url for each record, the url for this particular record is to `a1701.php`). At the moment the url displays fine but I want to exchange this url for the actual content of the file - this bit is the part that I can't get to work.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Is the URL on the same server or can it be anywhere on the internet?

Comment: Yes, the URL is on the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to accomplish this.

1. If the PHP file is always on the same server and is part of the web app, just include it. You would have to do some checking and validation to ensure that the file is there etc.
2. If the URL points to anywhere on the internet, insert it as an iframe.

Solution 1 (everything is local)

Assuming there is some function called `getPhpFileName` that returns the name of the PHP file. You need the actual name of the php file, not the url pointing to it. The file is read directly from the file system, not through the web server.

```
$phpFile = getPhpFileName($row['url']);
if ( file_exists($phpFile) ) {
    @include $phpFile;
}
```

example1.php (this is the file to be included)

```
<div>Hello Example1</div>
```

Solution 2 (iframe)
In this case, the iframe is returned and the browser will be responsible for getting the output from the url and inserting it on the page.

```
<iframe src="<?=$row['url']?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks @ryantxr, it's working now. I'm not sure why it wasn't before but I fiddled around with it using what you posted (option 1) and it works now.